# Bringing Can interface up - Operation not supported

Tags: kernel-modules, network-interface, modprobe

I am trying to use a Can module but I get an error message with the following commands:

```
$ sudo modprobe can
$ sudo ip link add dev can0 type can
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I have checked the [Elinux documentation](https://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up) related to CAN interfaces
and the procedure works with the virtual interface

```
$ sudo modprobe vcan
$ sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
$ sudo ip link set up vcan0
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a can bus module which communicates with a Raspberry Pi using SPI.

I had to enable the spi hardware interface:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0-overlay,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25 
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
```

Should be:

```
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25 
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835
```